# Как задать UILabel.text цвет текста и размер строки?

Tags: xcode

у меня есть NSString *abc к примеру, и есть UILabel* labtxt - к которому я хочу прикрутить цвет и размер.

```
[UIColor redColor]//цвет
font//Размер
```

только как прикрутить это всё не знаю.
Хотел бы задать ещё несколько попутных вопросов:
1.Сам же стринг цвета не может иметь? только нужно выставить компонент с нужным цветом?
2.Как текст сделать жирным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    self.labtxt.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.labtxt.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    self.labtxt.text = abc;
```

Как то так)